# Length of the well formed formula $(((p_0)\rightarrow ((p_1)∧(p_{32}))) \rightarrow ((((p_{13})∧(p_6))∨(p_{317})) \rightarrow (p_{26})))$

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus, formal-languages

How is the length of this well formed formula defined as $5$?

$\big(((p_{0})\rightarrow ((p_1) \land (p_{32}))) \rightarrow ((((p_{13}) \land (p_6)) \lor (p_{317})) \rightarrow (p_{26}))).$

(from Epstein’s textbook: *Classical Mathematical Logic: the Semantic Foundations of Logic*, p. 10)

According to the inductive definition, the number associated to $((p_1) \land (p_{32}))$ is $2$, and that associated to $(p_0)$ is $1$.

The rule for associating a number to a compound wff says (p. 7):

> If $A$ (call LHS) and $B$ (call RHS) are wffs and the maximum of the numbers assigned to $A$ and to $B$ is $n$, then each of $( \lnot A)$,  $(A \rightarrow B)$,  $(A∧B)$,  $(A∨B)$ is a compound wff to which we assign the number $n + 1$.

For the part $(((p_0)\rightarrow ((p_1) \land (p_{32})))$, it is seen that $(p_0)$ has length 1 and $((p_1) \land (p_{32}))$ has length $1+1=2$, since it is a compound wff and both $(p_1)$ and $(p_{32})$ has length 1. But for the compound wff $(((p_0)\rightarrow ((p_1) \land (p_{32})))$,$(p_0)$ has length $1$ and $((p_1)∧(p_{32}))$ has length $2$. How do I now find this length, when the lengths of LHS and RHS of the compound wff are not equal?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.
I suggest that you reference the text this problem is from (since an answer will need the correct definition of length), and provide an attempt at an answer in the question as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I encountered this example while reading Epstein’s Classical Mathematical Logic. Regarding the context, since I am just started with the text, every information would be helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sorry, after looking through the textbook, I was unable to understand their definition of length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the lengths of LHS and RHS of the compound well formed formula are not equal you have to take the *maximum* among them, according to Epstein's definition of the *length* $\mathrm{len}(\varphi)$ of a well formed formula $\varphi$ (in *Classical Mathematical Logic: The Semantic Foundations of Logic*, pp. 7-9).
More precisely, given a  binary connective $\circ$, then $\mathrm{len}(A \circ B) = \max\{\mathrm{len}(A),\mathrm{len}(B)\}+1$.

Concretely, the length of
\begin{align}
(((p_0) \to ((p_1) \land (p_{32}))) \to ((((p_{13}) \land (p_6)) \lor (p_{317})) \to (p_{26})))
\end{align} 
is 
\begin{align}
\max \{\mathrm{len}((p_0) \to ((p_1) \land (p_{32}))), \mathrm{len}((((p_{13}) \land (p_6)) \lor (p_{317})) \to (p_{26})) \} + 1.
\end{align}

Now, 
\begin{align}
\mathrm{len}((p_0) \to ((p_1) \land (p_{32}))) &= \max \{\mathrm{len}(p_0), \mathrm{len}((p_1) \land (p_{32})) \} + 1 
\\
&= \max\{1,2\} + 1 = 3
\\
\mathrm{len}((((p_{13}) \land (p_6)) \lor (p_{317})) \to (p_{26})) &= 
\max\{\mathrm{len}(((p_{13}) \land (p_6)) \lor (p_{317})), \mathrm{len} (p_{26})\} + 1
\\
&=\max\{ 3, 1\} + 1 = 4
\end{align}
because
\begin{align}
\mathrm{len}(((p_{13}) \land (p_6)) \lor (p_{317}) &= \max\{\mathrm{len}((p_{13}) \land (p_6)) , \mathrm{len}(p_{317})\} + 1 
\\
&= \max \{2,1\} + 1 = 3.
\end{align}

Therefore, the length of
\begin{align}
(((p_0) \to ((p_1) \land (p_{32}))) \to ((((p_{13}) \land (p_6)) \lor (p_{317})) \to (p_{26})))
\end{align} 
is

\begin{align}
\max \{\mathrm{len}((p_0) \to ((p_1) \land (p_{32}))), \mathrm{len}((((p_{13}) \land (p_6)) \lor (p_{317})) \to (p_{26})) \} + 1 
\\
= 
\max\{4,3\} + 1 = 5
\end{align}
as correctly stated in Epstein's book (p. 10).

Comment: thank you for the explanation!